# Scrape webpage with Beautifulsoup and export relevant data to csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, beautifulsoup

I am looking for feedback on my code, how I can simplify some operations, use more efficient methods or other best practices. This is my first web scraping project.

The goal here is to scrape a dentist's page for reviews and export to csv. I have not solved the issue with infinite scrolling, but ignore that for now. For the existing code, what can I improve?

I used ipython as I had to do a lot of trial and error to get beautifulsoup to provide me with the right output. The 4th review is in a different format than every other review on the site, and caused Nonetypes to mess up most of my loops. I found solutions for this, but not sure if ideal either. Thanks in advance.

The full notebook is here: 
https://github.com/joepope44/dentist_reviews/blob/master/upwork-web-scrape-2nd-approach-v2.ipynb

The meat of the code is here though:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import re

url = 'https://www.toothssenger.com/118276-ofallon-dentist-dr-edward-logan#read_review'
r = requests.get(url)
html_doc = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "lxml")

blocks = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class" : "jsReviewItem"}, limit=20)
one_block = soup.find("div", attrs={"class" : "jsReviewItem"})

records = []

#TO DO: handle infinite scrolling on webpage

for block in blocks:

    #review number
    review_num = block.select("div b")[0]
    if len(review_num) > 0:
        review_num = review_num.text.strip()
    else:
        review_num = "NaN"

    #reviewer name
    name = block.select("span")[1]
    if len(name) > 0: 
        name = name.text.strip()
    else:
        name = "NaN"

    #date published
    date = block.select('span[itemprop="datePublished"]')
    if len(date) > 0:
        date = date[0].text.strip()
    else:
        name = "NaN"

    #review text 
    review = block.find("span", {"itemprop":"reviewBody"})
    if review is not None:
        review = review.text.strip()    
    else: 
        review = "NaN"

    #select ratings tag and count the number of icons for each rating type
    ratings = block.select('div[class="mb-0-20"]')

    if len(ratings) > 0:

        #facilities ratings
        fac = ratings[0]
        fac_rating = (len(list(fac.find_all("i"))))

        #service rating
        serv = ratings[1]
        serv_rating = (len(list(serv.find_all("i"))))

        #painless rating
        painless = ratings[2]
        painless_rating = (len(list(painless.find_all("i"))))

        #results rating
        results = ratings[3]
        results_rating = (len(list(results.find_all("i"))))

        #cost rating
        cost = ratings[4]
        cost_rating = (len(list(cost.find_all("i"))))

    else:
        ratings = "NaN"

    records.append((review_num, name, date, review, fac_rating, serv_rating, painless_rating, cost_rating))   

print(records[0])
```